# program prints outs response to every character in the array, just need it to print out if the value is found or not once

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        System.out.println("Please enter an integer:");

        int userInput = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] == userInput) {

                System.out.println("value found!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("value not found!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so lets say the user inputs 3, i would like it to print out value found just once but instead it prints out or if the user inputs a numbers not it the array, i would like it to say value not found only once rather than it repeating it for every number in the array. I would just like to compare the number input by the user and see if it is found in the array.

```
value not found!
value not found!
value found!
value not found!
value not found!
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I can think of would be to use a flag.

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i] == userInput) {
        found = true;
        break;    // can end the loop since value was found
    }
}

if(found) {
    System.out.println("value found!");
} else {
    System.out.println("value not found!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this is that you're printing out the result of the `if` statement on each and every iteration of the loop.

Instead, what you'd want to do is setup a `boolean` value before the loop and set it to `true` if the value is found.

Then, **after** the loop completes, you can check to see if that `boolean` was ever set to `true`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer:");

    int userInput = input.nextInt();

    boolean valueFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] == userInput) valueFound = true;
    }

    if (valueFound) {
        System.out.println("Value Found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Value NOT Found!");
    }
}
```

---

**Result:**

```
Please enter an integer:
3
Value Found!
```